# Why are system call arguments copied by the kernel?

Tags: kernel

Why does the kernel copy system call arguments from the user space to the kernel space ?

Why can't the kernel access the system call arguments directly from the user stack?

Answer (score 3):

System calls copy arguments to kernel memory if the arguments were allocated in userspace memory. The reasons for this are security and reliability.

Suppose that the kernel did NOT make its own copy of arguments that are allocated in userspace memory. This would mean that potentially, that data that exists in userspace memory could be modified in the middle of the system call. This is detrimental to security and reliability. To prevent this from occurring, the kernel will immediately copy userspace arguments into kernel memory. Kernel memory cannot be accessed by userspace.

The kernel has UNLIMITED POWER to do whatever it wants, so system calls will perform checks to make sure that passed-in parameters are "safe" and not malicious. However, if the kernel did not make its own safe copy, then a userspace program, in theory, could swoop in after the kernel's checks, modify memory, and manipulate the kernel into doing bad, unsafe, and unreliable things.

Answer (score 0):

Because the kernel space stack is different from user space stack. The code that transfers control from user space to kernel space understands this. It hides the complexity for the following code by copying things. IF the variables were to stay in the user space, all the other kernel code would also need to 'understand' this - that such and such variables are to be found in user space stack, versus some other variables are to be found in the kernel stack.

Comment: I don't think that is the reason why arguments are copied. I refuse to believe that they are copied because of convention. Memory to memory copies are expensive. And system call invocation happens regularly.  In spite of that, if the kernel is copying arguments, there must be a real good reason.